# CSS: how to get scrollbars for div inside container of fixed height

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="FixedHeightContainer">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="Content">
    ..blah blah blah...
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.FixedHeightContainer
{
  float:right;
  height: 250px;
  width:250px;  
}
.Content
{
  ???
}
```

Due to its content, the height of `div.Content` is typically greater than the space provided by `div.FixedHeightContainer`. At the moment, `div.Content` merrily extends out of the bottom of `div.FixedHeightContainer` - not at all what I want.

How do I specify that `div.Content` gets scrollbars (preferably vertical only, but I'm not fussy) when its height is too great to fit?

`overflow:auto` and `overflow:scroll` are doing nothing, for some bizarre reason.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

setting the `overflow` should take care of it, but you need to set the height of `Content` also. If the height attribute is not set, the div will grow vertically as tall as it needs to, and scrollbars wont be needed.

See Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/1/

Comment: Okay - thanks. So I need to specify a height for div.Content? I assumed it would work out from the container that it wouldn't fit, and apply scrollbars on that basis.

Comment: If you give `Content` a fixed height, you shouldn't give `FixedHeightContainer` a fixed height, because you can't know how high your title will be, so `Content` may be pushed out. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/2/ You should set the fixed height **only** on the element with `overflow: scroll`. See http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/3/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/4/

Comment: I see your point (from the first link) but the title text is known and is too short to break over a line unless the user inflated the text to an impractical size.

Comment: Is there a way to have a short height and hide the scroll-bar at the same time?  this way when users drag down on mobile devices, they will see that they are scrolling down, but without the cumbersome of seeing 2 scroll-bars on their browser?

Comment: @blackhawk - Not that I know of. You may need to use Javascript for this. Specifically I am thinking of the jQuery Draggable library: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ -one thing to consider is... how will desktop users know to scroll?

Comment: Thanks @Dutchie432.  I will use CSS media queries to display this feature only on small width devices, then on desktop sizes, show it differently.

Comment: `height: auto;` not working in this case. any suggestions?

Comment: The height has to be hard-coded to a numeric value. If you specify "height:auto" the container should grow in height to fit the content, thus eliminating the need for scrollbars in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, here is my approach = a simple one that works for me:

```
<div id="outerDivWrapper">
   <div id="outerDiv">
      <div id="scrollableContent">
blah blah blah
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

html, body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0em;
}

#outerDivWrapper, #outerDiv {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0em;
}

#scrollableContent {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0em;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a great question because the answer is not immediately obvious, for such a simple task. The problem has hit me several times over the years, and It seems I always have to think about it before I get it right.

Below is my solution which uses (only) two CSS-classes, 'innerDiv' and 'outerDiv'.

```
<div id="outerDiv">
  <div id="innerDiv">
     A <p> B <p> C <p> D <p>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
    #outerDiv
    { height : 200px;
      margin : 44px; border: solid 4px Red;
    }

    #innerDiv
    { height     : 80%;
      overflow-y : auto;
      border     : solid 4px Green; font-size: 300%;
    }
</style>
```

Why does that work, and why do I say the answer is "*not immediately obvious*"?

In the example above both the outerDiv and innerDiv have fixed height because we set the height: -property for both of them.

We have the innerDiv height less than the height of the outerDiv. Therefore innerDiv "fits" into the outer-div and therefore the outer div should not get a scrollbar, right? Yes except if the innerDiv has so much content that it does not fit into the fixed height of the innerDiv but overflows. Therefore the question is **how can we prevent the inner div from "overflowing"?**

The way to prevent the innerDiv from overflowing is to give it the attribute "overflow: auto", or "overflow-y: auto" if we just want to prevent vertical overflow.

The reason the solution is "not immediately obvious" is this: The *default value of 'overflow' is NOT 'auto', but 'visible'*.

One might (erroneously) assume that the default value of overflow is  "auto", because then everything should be auto-matically taken care of, right? Not so fast, the default of overflow is **'visible'**, NOT 'auto'.

So if you remove the "overflow-y:auto" from the example above there will be no scrollbars. If you remove it but add it to the *outerDiv*, the outer div will have the scrollbar, which is NOT what we want. If you have it in both then only innerDiv will have it.

Answer (score 3):

Code from the above answer by Dutchie432

```
.FixedHeightContainer {
    float:right;
    height: 250px;
    width:250px; 
    padding:3px; 
    background:#f00;
}

.Content {
    height:224px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="FixedHeightContainer">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="Content">
    ..blah blah blah...
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.FixedHeightContainer
{
  float:right;
  height: 250px;
  width:250px;  
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

/*SCROLLBAR MODIFICATIONS*/

.FixedHeightContainer::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
}

.FixedHeightContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #909090;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.FixedHeightContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)Set the height and width of `div.Content` smaller or equal as per design(preferably smaller). You may use `px` or pcnt as `unit`. 
2)Now bring `overflow-y` property and set the value `auto`. 

CSS:

```
<style>
        .FixedHeightContainer 
        {
            float:  right;
            height: 250px;
            width:  250px;
            border: 1px solid red; 
        }
        .Content
        {
            height: 65%;
            width:  95%;
            overflow-y: auto;
            border: 1px solid red; 
        }
    </style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="FixedHeightContainer">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="Content">
    Any length/size of content.
  </div>
</div>
```