# Scroll over content with fixed position and specified top property drops the last part

Tags: html, css, fixed

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3p9urx4y/
I am trying to make mobile navigation that has to be placed under the header. But if I am specifying the next properties:

```
.list {
   top: 50px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

The last 50px of the content is missing because **top** property is not zero. I was trying to make the outer div with padding-top of 50px, but in this case scrolling appears at header area and this is not expected behavior.
We could specify the **margin-bottom** of the last list child and that helps:

```
.item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

But that is the trick and I am trying to find better solution.
I have found this question [Scroll part of content in fixed position container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154250/scroll-part-of-content-in-fixed-position-container) but I need something different. My header has to be fixed and navigation menu has to slide from the right side when user clicks the navigation button.

**Edited:** http://jsfiddle.net/3p9urx4y/ new example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *.list* has *height: 100vh*, so it will occupie the equivalent of 100% of the screen's height no matter its position.

One solution would be setting the list height to `calc(100vh - 50px)`. I've edited the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxc1veo6/2/).

The *calc* function allows you to execute calculation when specifying a css property. More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Comment: I like this solution and it works fine. But only one question, does IE supports calc functions? :D

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc, it is partially supported by IE 9+, meaning that it does not work in many use cases. I don't think there's any problem with your case. Just try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Give the header a position of fixed, a height and a width, don't forget to give it a z-index...then your navigation below it should be fine I can toss it more suggestions it you need me #cheers

Comment: If it is positioned absolute, relative,or fixed other floating elements with higher z-index will appear close to the user, giving the header a higher z-index will make everything floated element scroll under it.