# Dynamic table not displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create a table dynamically through the backend. I've stepped through my code and cannot find any problems. The table simply doesn't show. Here is the code -

```
Table tblEmployeeList = new Table();

foreach (DataRow row in dtEmployList.Rows)
{
    TableRow tRow = new TableRow();

    foreach(DataColumn dCol in dtEmployList.Columns)
    {
        TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
        tCell.Text = row["Username"].ToString();
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
    }
    tblEmployeeList.Rows.Add(tRow);
}
```

Comment: So what does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: I should of thought to check that! Thanks. It does not contain the table anywhere. Do I need to create the table in the front end first and then use it to create new rows and cells/

Comment: Yes. you should create a table in front end first with runat="server"

Comment: I tried that, no change.         <table runat="server" id="tblEmployeeList">
           
        </table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a html table on server side but did not added in the html of the page. Add a div in HTML make it runat="server". Add the current table in DIV after you are finished adding rows.

In HTML

```
<div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
```

In code bahind

```
div1.Controls.Add(tblEmployeeList); //This will show the table in the page
```

Your code would be

```
Table tblEmployeeList = new Table();
foreach (DataRow row in dtEmployList.Rows)
{
        TableRow tRow = new TableRow();

        foreach(DataColumn dCol in dtEmployList.Columns)
        {
            TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
            tCell.Text = row["Username"].ToString();
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
        }

        tblEmployeeList.Rows.Add(tRow);
 }
div1.Controls.Add(tblEmployeeList); //This will show the table in the page
```

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge and help!

Comment: Is it possible to have the table continue on the right side instead of havving to scroll down to reach the bottom of the table?

Comment: You are probably looking for scroll bars around table, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646708/css-how-to-get-scrollbars-for-div-inside-container-of-fixed-height